# How to estimate measure of union of sets?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a space with [a real-valued measure](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Measure) $\mu$ and let $A_n \subset X, \, n \in \mathbb{N}, $ be a family of measurable sets. Let us assume that the inequalities $\mu(A_n) >\frac 1 2 $  for each $n \in \mathbb{N} \,\,$ and $\mu(A_i \cap A_j) \le \frac 1 4 $ if $i\neq j$ are valid. How to prove or disprove $$\mu \left(\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n \right) >1? $$

Comment: One may assume $X=\mathbb{R}.$